# R - Testing which rows of a multi-column dataframe contain keyword

Tags: r, dplyr, boolean

Assume a dataframe `dat` with p-values.

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c("0.12", "0.12", "0.12*"), 
                  var2 = c("0.12", "0.12", "0.12"), 
                  var3 = c("0.12", "0.12", "0.12"))
```

How do I test which rows contain an asterisk?

Attempt 1:

```
dat %>%
+ mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.rows = contains('\\*'), isTRUE))
   var1 var2 var3 anyTRUE
1  0.12 0.12 0.12    TRUE
2  0.12 0.12 0.12    TRUE
3 0.12* 0.12 0.12    TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_detect/grepl` - `contains/matches/starts_with/ends_with` are all `select-helpers` used to match and select column names based on a pattern.  Here, we want to detect rows having a pattern.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(everything(), ~ str_detect(.x, fixed("*"))))
```

-output

```
dat
   var1 var2 var3 anyTRUE
1  0.12 0.12 0.12   FALSE
2  0.12 0.12 0.12   FALSE
3 0.12* 0.12 0.12    TRUE
```

NOTE: `fixed` is used as the `pattern` by default uses `regex` mode and `*` is a metacharacter to specify zero or more of the character preceding it.  Either escape (`\\`) or use `fixed` (which would be faster)

---

Or using `base R`

```
dat$anyTRUE <-  Reduce(`|`, lapply(dat, grepl, pattern = "*", fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct and clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach with `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% 
  unite(check, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(check = str_detect(check, '\\*'))
```

```
  check  var1 var2 var3
1 FALSE  0.12 0.12 0.12
2 FALSE  0.12 0.12 0.12
3  TRUE 0.12* 0.12 0.12
```